# Log all received data (headers, IP, etc.) to db for each aspx page request

Tags: asp.net, exception, logging

We are building asp.net application in which we want to log the received data (IP, http headers, etc) to database for every page request.

How to organize aps.net application, so that we are able to make a log to db even in case of exception?
Is this a good idea?
Should we write data to db in a new thread, so that it doesn't slow down the response?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using IIS7, take a look at [Failed Request Tracing](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731798%28WS.10%29.aspx).  You can set up rules that will log all sorts of details about the request given certain error conditions.  The XML file contains the request information, headers, and details about all of the HttpModules and HttpHandlers that processed the request.

Comment: Thanks, it is a good idea, but we prefer to do it from the code, and without deeper configuration of IIS.
It is easy to change somebody's code, but very difficult to change somebody's IIS configuration because configuration changes are usually not documented.

Comment: When you enable failed request tracing, it just adds a key to your web.config.  You can put this same key in your web.config in Visual Studio and keep it in TFS with all of your other code.  That way you don't have any configuration issues when migration code.