# In which method to write the log to db?

Tags: asp.net, web-applications, web

We would like to logg request data, performance data, etc. at the end of the each page request.
On the beginning of the request we create collection (parameter, value) and in it we store basic data like IP, language, headers etc.
Then we store this collection in current request (HttpContext.Current).
During the request we insert several other data to this collection like performance of certain methods, certain parameters, etc.
At the end of the request we want to store all parameters and values from this collection to database.

Where should we place the code that makes the writing of this collection to db? In some event method of master page? Somewhere else?

Comment: Refer to his previous question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4830025/log-all-received-data-headers-ip-etc-to-db-for-each-aspx-page-request for more context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you should write special HttpHandler just for this purpose ? If you want to log exceptions and errors take a look at [ELMAH](http://code.google.com/p/elmah/) and [log4net](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/).

Answer (score 2):

If you are custom coding this, you can make it part of every page request by having it part of the global.asax file. If you need the full page information, you can use a custom Page class to derive your pages from and add some instrumentation.

There are other tools out there, as David has mentioned.

Comment: Please stop adding signature lines